# AdapterName and encoding

Tags: networking, visual-c++

I had a problem getting the network adapter name using IP Helper. I get

> Adapter Name: {D387BCE2-FD49-4AFA-AA49-E7634ED15008} Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V

. How can this be translated into a regular readable string? At the same time, receiving the description of the network adapter is normal

```
PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapter = pAdapterInfo;
while (pAdapter) 
{
    ::set->Log(LOGINFO, "Adapter Name: %s %s\n", pAdapter->AdapterName, pAdapter->Description);
    ::set->Log(LOGINFO, "IP Address: %s\n", pAdapter->IpAddressList.IpAddress.String);

    pAdapter = pAdapter->Next;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `pAdapter->AdapterName`, use `pAdapter->FriendlyName`, as described here: [IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES_LH structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_adapter_addresses_lh).

Note that this is a Unicode string (`PWCHAR` rather than `PCHAR`), so you'll need to modify your format specifier accordingly, or convert the string.